# How can I delete the URL history in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When you open TortoiseGit for cloning a repository, under Clone existing repository, it fills the URL drop menu with repositories that were already cloned before. However, I want to clean this history. How can I achieve that? The reason I am doing this, is because I was using a company's laptop, and now I want to remove everything on it. I have already successfully removed my git credentials from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [TortoiseGit documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html) explains how to do this. It cannot be linked to directly, so here's an excerpt. It's most easily found by searching inside that page for *2.87*.

Essentially you need to go to the **Settings dialog** and then select **Saved Data** in the tree on the left. You can clear all kinds of things there.

> Figure 2.87. The Settings Dialog, Saved Data Page The Settings Dialog,
>   Saved Data Page
>
> [image]
>
> For your convenience, TortoiseGit saves many of the settings you use,
>   and remembers where you have been lately. If you want to clear out
>   that cache of data, you can do it here.
>
> **URL history**
>
> Whenever you checkout a working tree, merge changes or use
>   the repository browser, TortoiseGit keeps a record of recently used
>   URLs and offers them in a combo box. Sometimes that list gets
>   cluttered with outdated URLs so it is useful to flush it out
>   periodically.
>
> If you want to remove a single item from one of the combo boxes you
>   can do that in-place. Just click on the arrow to drop the combo box
>   down, move the mouse over the item you want to remove and type
>   **Shift+Del**.

Comment: I've cleared every one of these, yet the program still seems to be caching the origin remote path of my repository, which has changed on the git server and means I now can't access it.  Any advice ?

Comment: @AdamJones you might want to ask a new question to get more exposure. I can't answer this I'm afraid, I haven't had Windows or tortoisegit in years, sorry.